# Creating a Table using CSV fields and inserting rest of records

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to

- create a `table` with an fields I get from `fgetcsv()`.
- `table-name` field will be a date (like `13/10/2012`). I  want to append it to another string and use this as my table name.

My code so far:

```
if (($handle = fopen($this->filetemp, "r")) !== FALSE) {

    $ctr = 1;
    $tablename ="";

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if($ctr ==1) {

            $tablename =  $data[19];

            $query = "CREATE TABLE  ". $tablename ."( PlayerName VARCHAR(60),Handycap INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,Score INT NOT NULL,Front DOUBLE NOT NULL,Back DOUBLE,Prize VARCHAR(80));" ;
            mysqli_query($this->dbconn,$query);

            $name = str_replace("'"," ",$data[9]);
            mysqli_query($this->dbconn,"INSERT INTO  ". $tablename . " (PlayerName,Handycap,Score,Front,Back) VALUES ('$name', '$data[10]', '$data[11]','$data[12]','$data[13]')");

            $ctr++;
        }
        else if ($ctr > 1)  {
            $name = str_replace("'"," ",$data[9]);
            mysqli_query($this->dbconn,"INSERT INTO  ". $tablename . " (PlayerName,Handycap,Score,Front,Back) VALUES ('$name', '$data[10]', '$data[11]','$data[12]','$data[13]')");

            $ctr++;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

- for the moment I'm just trying to use the date which is at index 19

  But the table isn't created!! when I try it. I've also tried creating the table name with other index values but it still doesn't work.

I think im approaching this in the wrong way completely any help would be appreciated. cheers!

Sampel CSV records:

> "Golf Club","Competition results report","October Monthly Medal -
>   13/10/2012 [Stroke]"," Player
>   name","H'cap","Score","Front","Back","New Handicap","firstname,
>   secondname","9","66","34.5","31.5","","Players printed:",1,"Report
>   produced by Genesys Convenor.","Printed on:",13/10/2012,"Page no:",1
>
> "Golf Club","Competition results report","October Monthly Medal -
>   13/10/2012 [Stroke]"," Player
>   name","H'cap","Score","Front","Back","New Handicap","firstname,
>   secondname","18","66","33.0","33.0","","Players printed:",2,"Report
>   produced by Genesys Convenor.","Printed on:",13/10/2012,"Page no:",1

Comment: `var_dump()` to check `$data` has values as expected. And `dbconn` a valid handle? Where are collecting error response from `mysql_query()`?

Comment: `mysql_*()` API are deprecated. Use either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension instead. [Deprecated mysql_*()](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)

Comment: the values in the $data array are being returned. the problem is when i try to use it as the database name. i can use a regular string as the db name and it works. cheers for the advice i will use mysqli in future.

Comment: still very much stuck on this??

Comment: Share the top five lines of the CSV file in the post.

Comment: ive uploaded a section of the csv.

Comment: what to do [when you get answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV in post has helped; use the apostrophe for the table name.

change below code:

```
$tablename =  $data[19];
```

to :

```
$tablename =  "`".$data[19]."`";
```

It'll be easier if you debug using functions like `var_dump()`

PS: please stop using deprecated APIs.

Comment: thanks! ive changed over to mysqli as you can see above. also tried using you advise with the code above and it still doesnt seem to work?? im stumped

Comment: my apologies; updated the my post few seconds back. Usage of `apostrophe` around table name. Check it

Comment: Thanks a million SparKot! that solution worked. can you tell me why this was happening? im eager to know why so i dont make that mistake again. thanks!

Comment: @eoin Those are called `quoted identifiers`. From [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html) it's discouraged to use table names with "/" ;-) Also find valid characters over there.